# Show buttons in window taskbar thumbnail preview - Java

Tags: java, windows, winapi

How can i show buttons in taskbar's thumbnail preview like below,

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this in a java application?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this can only be done using native code and it will only work on specific versions of windows.

Here is the official documentation you will need.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx

Microsoft calls this "Thumbnail Toolbars":
[image]

You could use the code provided here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391703(v=vs.85).aspx

Write a custom c++ function, compile a DLL and call it with JNI. Then set some callbacks so that your c++ code can tell your java application when a button has been pressed.

You can get the necessary HWND from Swing.

I hope this will provide some help.